# Is it possible to see all changes that occur because you change a css class in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to fix a presentation bug in Google Chrome.  When I change one class, the page looks correct.  However, if I change every attribute of class A to those of class B, the presentation is still wrong.  Therefore, one of the child elements has a different style applied when I change the style.

Is there a way to quickly see all the changes in the computed styles on all elements that occur because you change a class on one element?

Answer (score 0):

With an element selected, click on the '+' in the upper right corner of the inspector. This will allow you to write a new rule.